# Bijection $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

Prove  that there is only  one monоtone bijection $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N},  0 \in \mathbb{N}.$

Is $n \mapsto n$ the answer?

Comment: $n\mapsto n$ is one of the example, but giving that only does not answer the question. You have to show that it is the only one.

Comment: The identity mapping is indeed a monotone bijection, so if you believe the statement it has to be it.

Comment: Hint: Bijection=Injection +surjection. so you need send each point to a different point and make sure that the range is the codomain. try to work that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a proof, assume that $f(0) \neq 0$, look at the value of $f(1)$ and use the monotonicity to find a number not in the image. Repeat as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is.

HINT: If $g:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ is some other function, let $$m=\min\{n\in\Bbb N:g(n)\ne n\}\;,$$ and consider two cases, $g(m)<m$ and $g(m)>m$.